# App Showing Wrong Resolution When Deployed To AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, web, frontend, aws-amplify

I created a web app using React. After I deployed it to AWS Amplify, I found that the deployed app had a lower resolution than my test version in the local environment. (Everything in the deployed one appears larger than normal.) What could cause this inconsistency?

Please let me know if you need more details. This is the first question I've asked in StackOverflow. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the zoom in Chrome locks to a certain % for specific domains. Make sure is 100% for both test and deployed sites as the domain changes.